# Is FILE * not a lvalue?

Tags: c++

trying to decipher my first big program, which is a LISP interpreter, in that case. I am totally new to the world of understanding someone else's code, and it seems far more complex than coding oneself.

I can hardly produce a minimal version of my current difficulty, as my current difficulty resides in minimizing the existing code in order to better grasp it, and I encounter bugs almost at each modification I try.

The interpreter uses Current_Input and Current_Output globals to abstract reading and writing to and from files and widgets. I am just trying to make it write to stdout.

The relevant lines are :

```
Current_Output = alloc_objet(sizeof(Widget *));
objet_type(Current_Output) = OWIDGET;
Owidget(Current_Output) = Wtext;
```

Allocating an object (the uber-type), telling it its real type is "WIDGET", and assigning the Widget Wtext to it.

The type OFILE already exists, and has a macro Ofile similar to the Owidget macro, here are both :

```
#define Owidget(objet) (* ((output_widget) objet + JMP))
#define Ofile(objet) ((FILE *) objet + JMP)
```

I wanted to replace the three relevant line thus :

```
Current_Output = alloc_objet(sizeof(FILE *));
objet_type(Current_Output) = OFILE;
Ofile(Current_Output) = stdout;
```

which produces the following error :

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment Ofile(Current_Output) = stdout;
```

This line :

```
printf("%d", Ofile(Current_Output));
```

Produces this warning :

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘FILE* {aka _IO_FILE*}’ [-Wformat=]
```

leading me to believe I have a FILE * on the left side of the bugging line, to which I want to assign stdout, another FILE *.

What is wrong here?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure this is C++ code? It looks more like ordinary C.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`FILE*` is a type, it doesn't have rvalueness / lvalueness.

You're passing `((FILE *) objet + JMP)` which is a temporary which is an rvalue.

Comment: Good answer. Put simplistically :- "You are trying to assign to the result of a calculation - and you can't do that."

Comment: Why does it work on the Owidget macro, please? (output_widget is really typedef Widget * output_widget). And widget is a X/motif widget

Comment: @pouzzler: `Owidget` dereferences the pointer to give an _lvalue_. `Ofile` just calculates a pointer value, giving an _rvalue_.

Comment: @pouzzler because the Owidget macro is dereferencing a pointer to which you can certainly assign something. Hence Floris' comment might be a bit misleading (even though its correct).

Comment: Therefore, if I did *Ofile(Current_Output) = *stdout, it would be correct? I bet it isn't, it doesn't seem feasible to pass the contents of stdout, just its address, no?

Comment: @pouzzler: you can't dereference `FILE*` (or even if you can on a particular implementation you shouldn't), it's an opaque type. The library implementation might know what it actually points to, but you don't. For that matter you can't/shouldn't add an offset to a `FILE*` either.